# Neo4J crashes after installing APOC plugin

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to install the APOC Full jar file (4.2.0.6) to my Neo4J instance that's running in a Google Compute VM. To do so, I've installed the JAR file from GitHub releases to the `/plugins` folder. Each time I restart or run the environment it crashes with the following output to logs:

```
"Some jar procedure files (apoc-4.2.0.6-all.jar) are invalid, see log for details."
```

There's really no additional details provided...

If I copy the default APOC Core library found withing `/labs`, it works. I've tried to download this same file from Github and it fails. I've verified that the same user/group permissions are applied to the downloaded file as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens for two reasons:

First is version mismatch. You can check which version you should use based on the version matrix, which is available at: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#version-compatibility-matrix. Unfortunately, it is not always up to date, but the APOC versions are if I understand correctly:

APOC 4.1.x.x -> Neo4j 4.1.x

APOC 4.2.x.x.-> Neo4j 4.2.x

APOC 4.3.x.x -> Neo4j 4.3.x

If I had to guess, you are probably using Neo4j 4.3 or 4.1 and using an APOC that is designed to work with Neo4j 4.2.

The other issue is that sometimes you have multiple APOC plugin files in the plugin folders, so that will also crash Neo4j.

Comment: Double-checked both of those and can confirm that's not the issue.

The strangest part is if I copy the existing APOC jar file located in `/labs` directory to `/plugins`...everything works fine. However, if I download that identical APOC jar file from Github to the `/imports` it errors out.

Comment: why would you add APOC to imports?

Comment: Sorry, typo, `/plugins`

Comment: Is it possible that this is somewhat related https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo-clienterror-procedure-procedurecallfailed-caused-by-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-roaringbitmap-container-org-roaringbitmap-arraycontainer-add-char/47477 ? I'm using roaringbitmap library in a custom plugin written by me, and in the plugin folder I have apoc too (neo4j 4.3 and apoc 4.3). It looks like my plugin is using roaringbitmap version defined in apoc instead of the one defined in my plugin. Is there a way to choose directly the version I have defined inside my plugin jar?

Comment: Solution for the issue I described before: https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo-clienterror-procedure-procedurecallfailed-caused-by-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-roaringbitmap-container-org-roaringbitmap-arraycontainer-add-char/47477/2?u=pinox101